# How to get inside this if statement (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm creating this simple quiz with 6 questions that I'm storing in an array. What I'm stuck with is that when you've reached the last question and you click 'Next', I'd like to show your results along with a text and a 'Restart' button.

What happens now though is that it show the last question again but without any answer-butons (I'm not getting into that if statement).

I'm pretty new to js, here's my code.

```
const startQuiz = document.querySelector('.container__start-btn');
const theQuestion = document.querySelector('.container__question');
const fourAnswers = document.querySelector('.container__answers');
const counter = document.querySelector('.container__counter__correct-answer');
const questionCounter = document.querySelector('.container__counter__question-nr');
const containerCounter = document.querySelector('.container__counter');

let currentQuestion = 0;
let count = 0;

const showQuestion = () => {
  startQuiz.innerText = 'NEXT';
  while (fourAnswers.firstChild) {
        fourAnswers.removeChild(fourAnswers.firstChild);
    }
    theQuestion.innerText = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    checkCounters();
}

const checkCounters = () => {
  counter.textContent = `Score: ${count}`;
  questionCounter.textContent = `Question: ${currentQuestion + 1}/${questions.length}`;
  generateAnswers();
}

const generateAnswers = () => {
  questions[currentQuestion].answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = answer.answer;
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.classList.add('right');
    }
    button.classList.add('btn');
    fourAnswers.appendChild(button);
    fourAnswers.classList.remove('hide');
  })
  fourAnswers.onclick = () => {
    const selected = event.target;
    if (selected.classList.contains('right')) {
      selected.classList.add('selectedRight');
      count++;
      counter.textContent = `Score: ${count}`;
    }
    if (!selected.classList.contains('right')) {
      selected.classList.add('selectedWrong');
    }
    const rightA = document.querySelector('.right');
    rightA.classList.add('selectedRight');
  }
   currentQuestion++;
  if (currentQuestion > questions.length) {
    console.log('inside if');
    startQuiz.innerText = 'START';
    theQuestion.innerText = `Good job! You got ${count} correct answers out of ${questions.length}. Press 'START' to go again.`;
    count = 0;
    currentQuestion = 0;
  }
}

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is the capital of Greece?',
    answers: [
      { answer: 'Athens', correct: true },
      { answer: 'Gothenburg', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Madrid', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Berlin', correct: false }
    ]
  },
    {
    question: 'What is the capital of Sweden?',
    answers: [
      { answer: 'Stockholm', correct: true },
      { answer: 'Lisboa', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Paris', correct: false },
      { answer: 'New York', correct: false }
    ]
  },
    {
    question: 'What is the capital of Portugal?',
    answers: [
      { answer: 'Lisboa', correct: true },
      { answer: 'Valencia', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Porto', correct: false },
      { answer: 'London', correct: false }
    ]
  },
    {
    question: 'What is the capital of Argentina?',
    answers: [
      { answer: 'Buenos Aires', correct: true },
      { answer: 'Santiago', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Amsterdam', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Beijing', correct: false }
    ]
  },
    {
    question: 'What is the capital of Thailand?',
    answers: [
      { answer: 'Bangkok', correct: true },
      { answer: 'Manila', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Rome', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Nicosia', correct: false }
    ]
  },
    {
    question: 'What is the capital of Denmark?',
    answers: [
      { answer: 'Copenhagen', correct: true },
      { answer: 'Oslo', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Beirut', correct: false },
      { answer: 'Los Angeles', correct: false }
    ]
  }
]

startQuiz.addEventListener('click', showQuestion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line 51 as follows.

```
if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
```

This is because the `questions.length` is 6 and the counter `currentQuestion` is 6 at the last question.

-- edit --

OK, try to modify like the following.

```
const showQuestion = () => {
  if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
    console.log('inside if');
    startQuiz.innerText = 'START';
    theQuestion.innerText = `Good job! You got ${count} correct answers out of ${questions.length}. Press 'START' to go again.`;
    count = 0;
    currentQuestion = 0;
    return;
  }

  startQuiz.innerText = 'NEXT';
  while (fourAnswers.firstChild) {
        fourAnswers.removeChild(fourAnswers.firstChild);
    }
    theQuestion.innerText = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    checkCounters();
   currentQuestion++;
}
```

And delete `currentQuestion++;` from `generateAnswers()`

Comment: I've tried that but then it shows the text and 'Restart' button instead of question nr 6

Comment: With the modifications it goes inside the if statement and it logs but it's also going to question nr 1 immediately.

Comment: Did you put `return;` statement at the end of the if statement?

Comment: Damn... Thank you so much for your help, it works!

Have to remember to use return so it doesn't continue, because I tried something similar before without the return... Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to be sure without a full reproducible jsfiddle, but I think it should be:

```
if (currentQuestion >= questions.length)
```

instead of:

```
if (currentQuestion > questions.length)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think about jsfiddle but next time I'll try to remember ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `if` in the beginning of the function and `return` inside of it so that you exit the function and do nothing else once you go into the if.

Currently what's happening is that the `foreach` is triggered even when the `currentQuestion` has passed the `questions.length`.

Also add the check to be more or equal.

```
const generateAnswers = () => {
  if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
    console.log('inside if');
    startQuiz.innerText = 'START';
    theQuestion.innerText = `Good job! You got ${count} correct answers out of ${questions.length}. Press 'START' to go again.`;
    count = 0;
    currentQuestion = 0;
    return; // end the function here so the other logic doesn't trigger.
  }
  questions[currentQuestion].answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = answer.answer;
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.classList.add('right');
    }
    button.classList.add('btn');
    fourAnswers.appendChild(button);
    fourAnswers.classList.remove('hide');
  })
  fourAnswers.onclick = () => {
    const selected = event.target;
    if (selected.classList.contains('right')) {
      selected.classList.add('selectedRight');
      count++;
      counter.textContent = `Score: ${count}`;
    }
    if (!selected.classList.contains('right')) {
      selected.classList.add('selectedWrong');
    }
    const rightA = document.querySelector('.right');
    rightA.classList.add('selectedRight');
  }
   currentQuestion++;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This does the same thing as my initial problem though. It shows the last question again but without the four buttons